# parsing text file using python for fields and their values

Tags: regex, mongodb, python-2.7

I am new to coding with python, learning it step by step. I have an assignment to parse text file and update database. The file would have some  status like
    ticket summary: 
    Frequency : 
    Action taken: < something like "restarted server">
    Status:

I want to parse this file, fetch the values for the fields like "ticket summary","frequency" etc. and put them in the database, where columns for them are defined. I am reading through python regex and sub string parsing, but not finding how to start. Need help

Comment: people might use " : " or "-" between a filed and its value, how to filter LHS and RHS

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't included an example, I will provide one to use here. I am assuming you have already installed mongodb, pymongo and have an instance of it running locally. as an example I am choosing my file to have the following formatting:

```
Frequency: restarted server, Action taken- none, Status: active
```

the code will use regex to extract the fields. for demos have a look here: [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/105)

```
import pymongo
import re

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['some-db']
freqgroup = re.compile(r"(?P<Frequency>Frequency[\:\-]\s?).*?(?=,)", flags=re.I)
actgroup = re.compile(r"(?P<ActionTaken>Action\sTaken[\:\-]\s?).*?(?=,)", flags=re.I)
statgroup = re.compile(r"(?P<Status>Status[\:\-]\s?).*", flags=re.I)

with open("some-file.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        k = re.search(freqgroup, line)
        db.posts.insert_one({"Frequency": line[k.end("Frequency"):k.end()]})
        k = re.search(actgroup, line)
        db.posts.insert_one({"ActionTaken": line[k.end("ActionTaken"):k.end()]})     
        k = re.search(statgroup, line)
        db.posts.insert_one({"Status": line[k.end("Status"):k.end()]})
```

Comment: This is the next stage actually. Let me provide more information. The piece above will definitely help in stage -2. I have a simple text file which I can take from status reported --------------------------------------------------------                        Environment : production
service: db health
incident description: prod database down
severity: 1
resolution: escalated

Comment: This is the next stage actually. Let me provide more information. The piece above will definitely help in stage -2. I have a simple text file which I can take from status reported --------------------------------------------------------                        Environment : production ||||
service: db health ||||
incident description: prod database down||||
severity: 1||||
resolution: escalated|||  first step is to write python code to parse this and extract values of these fields from text files. Second step is to use mongo db to store these values. last step is extraction . stuck at python

Comment: import re

myfile = open('//home/trishal/test','r')
mytext = myfile.readline()
for line in mytext:
 match = re.match(r'incident summary:\w\w\w',line)
 if match:
  print 'found', match.group()
else:
  print 'did not find'

Comment: im a bit confused by your comments, are you trying my code and failing?

Comment: No. what I meant is, my requirement is different and your code serves different purpose which is the next phase of my assignment

Comment: well try the regex demo to see what is happening. using this type of regex expression you can extract some text from the line with a tag such as "Frequency". then this is what i insert into the database later